# Facebook graph api "feed" not working for privacy option "EVERYONE"

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook graph api "feed" for posting messages to user wall

It works fine when I use `"ALL_FRIENDS"` and `"SELF"` privacy settings but when I use `"EVERYONE"` option, it again posts for friends only.

Any idea?